# How to display a text multilined inside a cell of a table in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cell, multiline

I am new to iphone development.I am parsing a xml file and displaying the title, date, view and summary in each row of a table.The contents of summary is big ,so only first 3 words are displayed in the cell. I increased the height of the row.Still 3 words are displayed in my cell.How summary should fit properly inside the cell and full content should be displayed.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why dont you set the "numberOfLines" property of the text label of a cell to 0.

just like this,

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
```

Good Luck.