# another question about line break in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, vb.net, line-breaks

I'm struggling with line break in UILabel.
I'm generating xml in vb.net and then parse it in iPhone application. xml contains text which initially contains html tags such as 
, so I can and need to replace these tags with something to add a linebreak in iphone

How can I do it? I tried `\n` , `\n\r`, they a not working

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253982/how-to-display-a-text-multilined-inside-a-cell-of-a-table-in-iphone/2254265#2254265) Best of Luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\n should work. Make sure you set `numberOfLines` to 0, and `lineBreakMode` to something that suits you.

Comment: I'm doing it, it's not working, label just shows "some text\nmore text"

Comment: I don't assign static text, I'm getting it from xml parsing. Can it be the case? I have \n in text and it looks like objective-c just ignores it. I'm so confused about it because I can see that it works for other people. I'm miising somthing simple but can't find it.

Comment: Check in the debugger what exactly you're assigning. Then compare it to the case if you assign the static text. Hopefully that would give you direction to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I found one interesting thing, I'm checking my string in debugger and I still can see 'some text\nmore text, but if I assign text manually like NSString *s = @"AAA\nBBB" it works and in this case in debugger \n looks thinner and paler. How can I replace my usual \n to thinner \n ?))

Comment: Thinner and paler? Can you post a screenshot with it? Also can you post code that replaces <br> with \n in your XML text?

Comment: Hi I solved the problem adding new line to xml like this: 
text = text.Replace("<br />", ControlChars.CrLf) this way didn't work:
text = text.Replace("<br />", "\n"). About thinner and paler, I know it sounds stupid, so I made a couple screenshots, this is working: http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/9135/screenshot20100810at183.png and this is not: http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/9135/screenshot20100810at183.png
Still can't understand it can you explain it? anyway thank you for help))

Answer (score 6):

If you read a string from an XML file, the line break \n in this string will not work in UILabel tekst. The \n is not parsed to a line break.

Here is a little trick to solve this issue:

```
// correct next line \n in string from XML file
NSString *myNewLineStr = @"\n";
myLabelText = [myLabelText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:myNewLineStr];

myLabel.text = myLabelText;
```

So you have to replace the unparsed \n part in your string by a parsed \n in a hardcoded NSString.

Here are my other label settings:

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0];   
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Most important is to set numberOfLines to 0 (= unlimited nr of lines in label).

No idea why Apple has chosen to not parse \n in strings read from XML?

Hope this helps,

Al

Comment: all I can say is "I LOVE YOU!!" dude!! I was trying to find an aswer and finally did with your post... The accepted answer should be yours!!